# Why I have a compilation error with Monoid from cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

When I have this import, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/monoid.html)

```
import cats.std.all._
```

The following code doesn't compile :

```
def merge(m1: Map[String, Int], m2: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = m1 |+| m2
```

I got this error :

```
value |+| is not a member of Map[String,Int]
```

When I remove the import, it works.
Is it an error in the doc or may I miss something ?

Comment: Are you using the `import cats.implicits._` ?

Comment: It was an error in the documentation to use both imports at the same time, when the next cats version will be published the docs will only mention `import cats.implicits._` (see the [source of the monoid docs](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/monoid.md) on github).

Comment: Thanks @PeterNeyens

Answer (score 0):

probably `|+|` is overrided in `cats.std.all._`. Just import from that lib only what is necessary for you.